# Simple electronics circuit simulation software for Mac

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

I want to learn how basic electronic components work and test some basic sensor output etc. My circuits are really simple so i don't need any fancy stuff.

I think MacSpice is CLI so it's too hard for me, i really need GUI app since i know hardly nothing about electronic circuits.

Which app lists electronic components with real names like "resistor 200" and don't use cryptic component codes which are hard to newbie?

Comment: Why not improve this to explain what specific problem you are trying to solve or why a free circuit simulator from the maker community isn't a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of a kind App http://icircuitapp.com/

It has IPad app as well. with simulation capablities

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

https://github.com/hneemann/Digital/blob/master/README.md

Works on my Mac great, it is similar to the Logisim program for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

[Qucs](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qucs/) describes itself as a circuit simulator with a GUI. It is free and available from SourceForge. The project is active and under development for updates. The link [here](https://easyeda.com/Selina/Circuit_Simulation_Software_for_Mac-DbmkUSQqZ) lists about 10 circuit simulation programs for the mac. The list is a couple of years old but the good simulations should still be available. [This link](https://alternativeto.net/software/circuit-simulator/?platform=mac) lists about 15 simulators for the mac.